# Visual Fox Pro 9 4 digit numbers

Tags: visual-foxpro

I'm searching for a commant for a question.

I have a 4 digit number like 3521, and the question is i need to find numbers where the first two digit is bigger then the last two.

Comment: So i need like 3+5 2+1 is good because 8>3
Any command for this?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your number is lnMyNumber:

```
lnMyNumber = 3521
? (Val(Left(Str(lnMyNumber, 4, 0),2)) > Val(right(Str(lnMyNumber, 4, 0),2)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Command Window example:

```
LOCAL unknownType
unknownType = 3521
? CompareSumsOfTwoBytePairs(unknownType) && returns true
unknownType = "3521"
? CompareSumsOfTwoBytePairs(unknownType) && returns true
unknownType = "YZAB"
? CompareSumsOfTwoBytePairs(unknownType) && returns true
unknownType = 35210
? CompareSumsOfTwoBytePairs(unknownType) && too long, returns false
* The following unexpected types return all false:
unknownType = .F.
? CompareSumsOfTwoBytePairs(unknownType)
unknownType = .Null.
? CompareSumsOfTwoBytePairs(unknownType)
unknownType = CREATEOBJECT("Form")
? CompareSumsOfTwoBytePairs(unknownType)
unknownType = DATE(2015, 2, 7)
? CompareSumsOfTwoBytePairs(unknownType)

FUNCTION CompareSumsOfTwoBytePairs(u)
    LOCAL c
    c = TRANSFORM(u)
    RETURN LEN(c) == 4 AND (SUBSTR(c, 1, 2) > SUBSTR(c, 3, 2))
ENDFUNC
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to keep the numbers as numbers vs forced string conversions.

```
n = 3521
? INT( n/100 ) > n-(INT(n/100)*100)

n/100 = 35.21... the int leaves just 35
```

and this same basis is in the other half...

```
n-(INT(n/100)*100)
3521 - ( INT( 3521/100) * 100 )
= 3521 - (  35 * 100 )
= 3521 - 3500 = 21

so 35 > 21
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a complete code than you can put in a function

```
    local lnVal, llReturn

    lnVal=35821

    llReturn=left(trans(lnVal),2)>right(trans(lnVal),2)

    return llReturn
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.